# what this syntax in typescript interface means?

Tags: angular, typescript

recently i want to implement observer pattern in my angular 4 app, i faced this syntax of code in typescript and i don't know what this means?

**the code:**

```
module Patterns.Interfaces {

    export interface IObservable {
        RegisterObserver(Observer: Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver);//Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver type?
        RemoveObserver(Observer: Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver);
        NotifyObservers();
    }
}
```

thanks for your helps.

Comment: Are you referring to the `module` declaration or the `interface` declaration? Or something else?

Comment: Start from documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: @Sid both ```module``` and ```Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver``` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an annotated version:

```
// There's a namespace named Patterns.Interfaces
module Patterns.Interfaces {
    // It has an interface named IObservable
    // It is visible outside this block ('export')
    export interface IObservable {
        // An IObservable has a function called RegisterObserver.
        // It takes one argument named 'Observer'.
        // 'Observer' is of type Pattern.Interfaces.IObserver.
        // You must pass this argument.
        // Its return type is unspecified, so is assumed to be 'any'
        RegisterObserver(Observer: Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver);//Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver type?
        // Same as above
        RemoveObserver(Observer: Patterns.Interfaces.IObserver);
        // An IObservable has a function called NotifyObservers.
        // It is called with no arguments.
        // Its return type is unspecified, so is assumed to be 'any'
        NotifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,i wasn't any familiar with namespaces in typescript and i didn't know what to search.